# How to store a single configuration document (no schema)?

Tags: mongoose

In Mongoose each document must conform to a schema and be stored in a collection of similar objects. For example, one can have a `User` collection populated with documents created with `User` schema.

Is there a way to create a document, in my case, I want to create a document with some configurations (application start time, total number of users, server configurations and so on). Aka "persistent config" file.

One way of doing it is — creating a `Config` schema and a `Config` collection and then saving the config document with a predefined `_id`. It allows retrieval of the document at a later time, since the id is known and is the same.

Is there another way (without schema and collection)?